# Join in MySQL with an UPDATE condition for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to perform a UPDATE JOIN query in MySQL

I need to do the following: Add the table_1.won to table_2.total_winnings for a given session

```
+++ Table_1 +++

--id--  --name--  --selection--  -potential_winnings--   -- won --  --session--
  1       John          a              67                    0           1
  2       Jame          b              10                    **10**      1
  3       David         c              43                    0           1
  4       Sam           b              20                    **20**      1
  5       Alex          b              30                    **30**      1
  6       Rob           b              1000                  0           2


 +++ Table_2 +++  (BEFORE)

--id--   --Total_winnings--   -- session --
  1              4534               1
  2              885                1
  3              0                  1
  4              5                  1
  5              10                 1
  6              5465               2
```

My desired output is below

input : winning selection = b
        session =1

```
 +++ Table_2 +++  (AFTER)

--id--   --Total_winnings--   -- session --
  1              4534               1
  2              **895**            1
  3              0                  1
  4              **25**             1
  5              **40**             1
  6              5465               2
```

I can do this by selecting each user from table_1 who has won and looping over there entry in table_2, but I have a large number of items to process now, so I think I need a join of somesort to accomplish this..

I'm currently doing

```
UPDATE table_2 SET Total_winnings = Total_winnings + 10 WHERE id = 2 AND session = 1
```

If anyone would know how to do this, or has a simple example of a SQL join with and UPDATE query that would be most useful. I have seen other examples of this, but I can never figure out what it going on in the SQL!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE table_2
join table_1 on table_1.id = table_2.id
SET Total_winnings = Total_winnings + won
WHERE session = 1 and selection = 'b'
```